# Free the stack implemented in C

Tags: c, stack, free

I implement a stack and its functions in C. Now after all the functions were called, I wanted to free the stack.

My question is should I free the base pointer of stack "st" first or just directly free the stack "st"? Both seems work in my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define init_size 10
#define increment 1

typedef struct sqStack
{
    int* top;
    int* base;
    int stack_size;
}sqStack;

int init_stack(sqStack* sq)
{
    if(sq->base==NULL)
    {
       sq->base = (int*)malloc(init_size*sizeof(int));
    }
    if(sq->base==NULL) exit(-1);
    sq->stack_size=init_size;
    sq->top=sq->base;
    return 1;
}
int push(sqStack* sq, int e)
{
    if(sq==NULL) exit(-1);

    if(sq->top-sq->base==sq->stack_size-1)//pointer top reaches the top of the stack
    {
        int* q = (int*)realloc(sq->base,(sq->stack_size+increment)*sizeof(int));
        if(q==NULL)  exit(-1);
            sq->base=q;
        sq->top=sq->base+sq->stack_size-1;
            sq->stack_size += increment;

    }
    *sq->top++=e;
    return 1;
}
int pop(sqStack* sq,int* e)
{
    if(sq==NULL) exit(-1);
    if(sq->base==sq->top)  exit(-1);
    sq->top--;
    *e=*sq->top;
    sq->stack_size--;
    return *e;
}
int top(sqStack* sq,int* e)
{
    if(sq==NULL) exit(-1);
    if(sq->base==sq->top)  exit(-1);
    *e=*(sq->top-1);
    return *e;
}
int empty(sqStack* sq)
{
    if(sq->base==sq->top) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int main() {
    sqStack* st= (sqStack*)calloc(1,sizeof(sqStack))  ;
    int e;
    init_stack(st);
    for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
        push(st,i+1);

    }
    for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",top(st,&e));
        printf("%d\n",pop(st,&e));
    }
    free(st->base);
    free(st);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:
12
12
11
11
10
10
9
9
8
8
7
7
6
6
5
5
4
4
3
3
2
2
1
1
each number locates on a single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is correct in terms of `malloc` and `free`.

You should only pass to `free` what was returned from `malloc` or `realloc`.  You allocate space for the struct and for the stack and you free both, so you're not leaking any memory.

You don't want to `free(st)` first because after doing so the memory that `st` was pointing to is no longer valid and you can't subsequently `free(st->base)` safely.  Also, because `free` knows nothing about the contents of the given memory, it doesn't attempt to free any pointers that the memory might contain.  So just calling `free(st)` leaks the memory in `st->base`.

Comment: So the reason I don't need to free(st->top); is because st->top=st->base; after I pop all the elements in stack??

Comment: @Liu If the stack is empty then yes they are the same, so you don't want to free twice.  But even if the stack isn't empty you don't want to do that.  In that case `st->top` would point somewhere in the middle of the array, which is not an address returned by `malloc` or `realloc`.

Comment: if you free the stack st, you only free the first address of st or the whole array??

Comment: @Liu If you tell `malloc` to allocate for example 100 bytes and it returns address 0x1234, when you pass 0x1234 to `free` it frees the 100 bytes it gave you.

Comment: so in my case, if pointer top is in the middle of the array,  and after I freed base, top is freed as well?

Comment: @Liu It's not proper to say that `top` is fre'ed because it doesn't point to an address that was returned by `malloc`, but yes the memory it points to has already been fre'ed.

Answer (score 1):

Every allocation should be paired with a corresponding `free`, so in your case that means freeing both `st->base` and `st` (in that order).  But your program performs its frees only immediately prior to termination, and anything it does not free will be reclaimed by the OS when the program does terminate.  A memory usage analyzer such as Valgrind could detect the difference for you, but in practice it does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. The reverse sequence might work but, if it did, this would be accidental.

The reason is that `free(st)` deallocates the memory in which the object `*st` is stored. The pointer `st->base` is stored in a part of this very memory. Suppose that some other task, or thread, acquired the same memory as soon as it had been freed. What then? That is, what would happen when `free(st->base)` were eventually called?

Answer: what would happen is undefined.

Even if it were still possible to retrieve an address from `st->base` (and it might not be possible), that address might have been overwritten by arbitrary data, in which case `free(st->base)`—interpreting the arbitrary data as an address—would ask the operating system to deallocate ... well, you don't know *what* it would ask the operating system to deallocate. One should hardly expect good results in this case.

You have done well. Your sequencing is correct.

**ADDITIONAL CONSIDERATIONS**

For security, modern operating system kernels sometimes automatically overwrite deallocated memory with null or random data. Also, they sometimes revoke a program's access to the hardware *page* via which deallocated memory had been (virtually) addressed, or tighten the bounds within which access is allowed. Some of these are more likely than others but I have seen at least two of the three occur. The point is that the kernel is free to do such things immediately, sooner, later or not at all, as the kernel prefers, according to the kernel's latest memory management and security algorithms, because your program is not supposed to care what happens to deallocated memory after the program has deallocated it.

Comment: So the reason I don't need to free(st->top); is because st->top=st->base; after I pop all the elements in stack??

Comment: I have not examined all your code so closely, but have examined only the two lines. Unfortunately, though I had some time yesterday, I shall have no more time available during the next week, but someone else might advise you. Good luck.